# Awaitable type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, async-await

I use async / await a lot in JavaScript. Now I’m gradually converting some parts of my code bases to TypeScript.

In some cases my functions accept a function that will be called and awaited. This means it may either return a promise, just a synchronous value. I have defined the `Awaitable` type for this.

```js
type Awaitable<T> = T | Promise<T>;

async function increment(getNumber: () => Awaitable<number>): Promise<number> {
  const num = await getNumber();
  return num + 1;
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
// logs 43
increment(() => 42).then(result => {console.log(result)})

// logs 43
increment(() => Promise.resolve(42)).then(result => {console.log(result)})
```

This works. However, it is annoying having to specify `Awaitable` for all of my projects that use async/await and TypeScript.

I can’t really believe such a type isn’t built in, but I couldn’t find one. Does TypeScript have a builtin awaitable type?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why do you need to specify `Awaitable` everywhere in your codebase? Either your function returns `T` or `Promise<T>`, either way your function can handle it

Comment: Also `type Awaitable<T> = T | Promise<T>` isn't that complicated that writing it in multiple projects would that big of a problem

Comment: @Aron But if you have multiple return lines, you would have to wrap every synchronized value in a promise, which is not bad, but you don't have to.

Comment: @Silvermind what do you mean by multiple return lines and every synchronised value? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Aron It is sort of what was added to the post. `() => 42` is invalid if you use `Promise<T>` as the signature, but you can just call `await 42` in typescript.

Comment: I quite like your `Awaitable<T>`. Might be worth doing an issue on the TypeScript issue list and a pull request adding it to `lib.es5.d.ts`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I created an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31394)

Comment: Is this actually the reason for the Feature Request of the `awaited` operator in TS3.9 that did not make is into the final release? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35998
It seems to exactly fill this gap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer to this question is: No, there is no built-in type for this.

In [`lib.es5.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/eb2297df022f6b1f284aff96e93c06097bb01ea5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts) and [`lib.es2015.promise.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/eb2297df022f6b1f284aff96e93c06097bb01ea5/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts), they use `T | PromiseLike<T>` for the various places your `Awaitable<T>` would make sense, for instance:

```
/**
 * Represents the completion of an asynchronous operation
 */
interface Promise<T> {
    /**
     * Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onfulfilled The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.
     */
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;

    /**
     * Attaches a callback for only the rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of the callback.
     */
    catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<T | TResult>;
}
```

There's nothing like your `Awaitable` in `lib.es5.d.ts` where they define `PromiseLike` and `Promise`.

I'd think if they'd defined one, they would use it in those definitions.

Side note: Based on those definitions, it probably makes sense to use `PromiseLike` rather than `Promise` in your `Awaitable`:

```
type Awaitable<T> = T | PromiseLike<T>;
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `async/await` will always cause the statement to be wrapped into a promise, so your function will always return a promise.
2. everything can be awaited, regardless of it being async or not, so a custom `Awaitable` type might just be redundant...

```js
async function test() {
    const foo = await 5;
    console.log(foo);

    const bar = await 'Hello World';
    console.log(bar);

    const foobar = await Promise.resolve('really async');
    console.log(foobar);
}

test();
```

[Link to the ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

You don't need extra typing imho, since your function will always have:

```js
async function foo<T>(task: () => T | Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
  const result = await task();

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The OP is clearly aware of how `await` works and that you can await a non-thenable. The question is about defining a type for a callback so that the function provided for the callback parameter may be either a function return `T` or a function returning `Promise<T>`.

Comment: it should help because: 1. `Awaitable` is redundant, since everything is awaitable by default; 2. as soon as you use the `async/await` keyword, then your function will always return a promise, hence the typing is always consistent (imho).

Comment: No, `Awaitable` isn't redundant; [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Awaitable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%0Aasync%20function%20works(fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Awaitable%3Cnumber%3E)%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%202%20*%20await%20fn()%3B%0A%7D%0Aasync%20function%20failsf(fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20number)%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%202%20*%20await%20fn()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20example()%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20Math.random()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aworks(example)%3B%0Afails(example)%3B).

Comment: *(Continuing my comment above since the link eats up the comment limit.)* OP specifically wants to cater to a callback that returns a promise and also one that doesn't, with proper typing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is correct. I want to specify the return type of the callback function that will be awaited.

Comment: here is fixed version [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Awaitable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%0Aasync%20function%20works(fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Awaitable%3Cnumber%3E)%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%202%20*%20await%20fn()%3B%0A%7D%0Aasync%20function%20fails(fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E)%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%202%20*%20await%20fn()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20example()%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20Math.random()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aworks(example)%3B%0Afails(example)%3B)

Comment: await always return Promise. so just declare it as promise

Comment: @JurajKocan - Please read [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021581/awaitable-type-in-typescript#comment98687491_56021698).