# How to unwrap a promise in a JSDoc type with ReturnType?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I have the following code:

```js
const foo = async () => {
  return 1
}
```

I want to add a type to a variable with the ReturnType of the function, but the type after resolving the promise.

If I try:

```js
/** @type {ReturnType<foo>} */
let bar
```

I get `Promise<number>`, but I want to get `number`.

Is it possible to achieve this **result in JSDoc**? How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011353/how-to-unwrap-type-of-a-promise?rq=1

Comment: this is not possible. you would need to remove the `async`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021581/awaitable-type-in-typescript

Comment: Thanks @Ifaruki, I guess it really is not possible. I'll wait a bit more, but if you'd like to post your comment as an answer I'll probably accept it soon.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to achieve this in JSDoc when you're working in a TS environment?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer my question got 4 downvotes and barely any attention without the TS tag. I figured that maybe adding the tag would draw more attention. Also because TS devs are more likely to know about this stuff. In this project I wasn't using TS (not by choice)

Comment: imho that seems a little underhanded since you're not working in a TS environment, nor is TS even relevant to the answer you're looking for. The TS tag is actually probably working against you since this is entirely possible in TS, and will be flagged as a duplicate. All I could suggest is creating a better, clearer more concise question. If you follow the appropriate SO Question guidelines, you shouldn't get downvoted - and an answer may eventually come.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer I have absolutely no idea how I can make it clearer, do you have any suggestions? If I provide more context people might understand _why_ I want to do it, but at the same time it'll only add more complexity. If I'm making the right or wrong decision is not relevant to me, I don't care if it's good or bad etc. I'm really just looking for how to do it or "no, it's not possible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the type `Awaited<T>`

```
/** @type {Awaited<ReturnType<foo>>} */
let bar
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to understand the core issue and why you want to implement like this. As you are using `async` before a function then it will create a promise. If you will call this method it will return a promise (`Promise<number>`).

**METHOD-1**

You can easily add return type of this function like I did below:

```
/**
 * Return a promise
 * @return {Promise<number>} A promise of type number.
 */
const foo = async () => {
  return 1
}
```

And same way you can with your variable like below:

```
/** @type {Promise<number>} */
let bar = foo();
```

**METHOD-2** - If you want to convert this to data type of number then their is no direct way ***but we can definitely do it using an extra function here. Just listen to promise using then method and pass the resolved value for assignment in the new function.***

In this your function will stay as is as it will always returns a promise.

```
/**
 * Return a promise
 * @return {Promise<number>} A promise of type number.
 */
const foo = async () => {
  return 1
}

/** @type {number} */
let x = -Infinity;
function assignVariable(myValue) {
  x = myValue;
  console.log(x);
}

foo().then(value => {
  assignVariable(value);
});
```

Please find working snippit here:

```js
const foo = async () => {
  return 10;
};

let x = -1;
function assignVariable(myValue) {
  x = myValue;
  console.log(x)
}

foo().then(value => {
  assignVariable(value);
});
```

Comment: I want `bar`'s type to be `number` because `foo` returns a `number` after the promise is resolved. In your method 2 `x` is the correct type, but you hard coded it to `number`. Instead of hard coding I'd like to figure out the type of the resolved promise.

Comment: **BOUNTY DISCLAIMER**: This answer has been auto-selected, however, it does **NOT** answer the question.

Comment: Let me clarify the problem here, you want the bar's type to be a number without specifying it explicitly. And you are assuming that foo returns a number and I think this is where you are misunderstood that we have made foo a Promise by adding async in front of it. So it will always return a Promise<number> not just number. Even if you add a callback using then method it still returns a Promise. I guess it would be better if you could explain the your core problem that you want to resolve using this. I gave you a valid workaround.